# Storyboard and Programmatic design simultaneously

Tags: ios

I use programmatic way to create design parts and I won't use storyboard for design. But at some design I feel it will be easy with storyboard, is it possible to do design in both storyboard and programmatic in one project simultaneously. If so please tell me the process.

Comment: arun your question is fine ,use both does not affect the memory for example  create the every element in attribute, it is easy to optimize your work and time at the same time dynamically you need to change the frame .x, .y, .width, .height for the element use progrmatically , the instance override the main , the new frame automatically take the new position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. Everything you can do in the designer you can do in code (though not vice versa).

You can instantiate the storyboard using the "UIStoryboard FromName" methods. From the storyboard object you can then use "InstantiateInitialViewController" to get the initial view controller of the storyboard. From this point on the storyboard segues will perform as expected.

If you want to jump to a certain part of the storyboard, you simply use the other method on UIStoryboard which takes an Identifier.vc.

Once you are done with your storyboard view controllers you can then get rid of it programmatically as expected (use pop/dismiss depending on how it was presented).

It is similar to the technique used for splitting large storyboards into smaller ones. If you google "splitting large storyboards" you will be able to find a lot of articles which will help you.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Most (if not all) of the objects you see in storyboard are part of the UIKit, which you'll see is imported at the top of every View Controller Xcode makes for you. You can add UI Objects, like a `UILabel`, to a View using `addSubview`, for instance.

Technically, you don't need to use the Interface Builder at all (and there was a time when you couldn't), it just makes things incredibly faster to produce.